# Script to delete all files in directory then email

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Need a script to delete all files in a directory then email once complete, I have the below as a template but unsure if this will work - of course no email component has been added!

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR="/var/www/public_html/docs/files/"
LIST=`ls -l $DIR | grep -v "total 0"`
FILES=`ls $DIR`
cd $DIR
if [ -z "$LIST" ]
then
  exit
else
  echo "Files Delete:"
  echo $FILES
  rm -f *
fi
```

Update:

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR="/home/test/test/docs/test/"
cd $DIR
rm -f *
```

Comment: Why is your code jumping through all those hoops? Wouldn't `rm -f /var/www/public_html/docs/files/*` or `rm -f "$DIR*"` be sufficient?

Comment: Why not give it a try and see what happens? I'd expect that `rm -f *` will work just fine.

Comment: `find /var/www/public_html/docs/files/ -type f -delete` is probably best here.

Comment: Thanks I've changed the script to be very basic now

Comment: On risk ist to `cd $DIR` without checking this change to dir. After that you want to remove all files. What, if your directory does not exist? What if the directory isn't accessible to the user running this script?

Comment: Indeed, it is better not to `cd` at all. USe `rm -f "$DIR/*"`; of course this could still fail if you have a large number of files in $DIR, which is one reason the `find` solution is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes:

You use all-caps DIR, LIST and FILES, but all-caps variables in shell scripts are, by convention, environment variables. You should use e.g.

```
dir='/var/www/public_html/docs/files/'
```

instead.

To find how many files are in a directory use

```
find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l
```

You use both LIST and FILES; it seems like you're tring to find out if there are any files before deleting them. There's no point to this from a functionality point of view but if you must conditionally echo the list of files it's better to make the decision this way.

```
if [ $(find "$dir" -type f | wc -l) -gt 0 ] ; then
    echo Files Delete:
    find "$dir" -printf '%f '
fi
```

Although you should be aware that this output cannot be reliably used to reconstruct the actual file names.

To actually delete the files you should again use `find`

```
find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -delete
```

Putting it all together

```
dir='/var/www/public_html/docs/files/'

if [ $(find "$dir" -type f | wc -l) -gt 0 ] ; then
    echo Files Delete:
    find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f  -printf '%f ' -delete
fi
```

Here I have combined the "print files" and "delete files" steps into a single invocation of `find`.